# How to parse JSON file from a column in BigQuery

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

This is the JSON file that I am trying to parse

`[{"message":"Value","code":"1234"}]`

I am trying to parse the message from the JSON
I think the challenge is because the JSON started with "[" instead of the more common "{"

This is the query that I thought was right but apparently it's not

`JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(response,'$[0].message')`

Please note that "response" is the name of the column a.k.a the json_string_expr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a typo in your real code/query?
Works for me as is - see example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '[{"message":"Value","code":"1234"}]' response
)
SELECT *, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(response,'$[0].message')
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row response                            f0_  
1   [{"message":"Value","code":"1234"}] Value
```

Comment: Nevermind, I just tried it again and it works, I think it didn't work before because I was using ```coalesce``` and I screwed up somewhere.

Comment: Wondering if I could ask for your help one more time. 
Now I am trying to parse 
```"{\n  \"type\":\"invalid\",\n  \"code\":\"invalidRequest\",\n  \"details\":\"Missing or invalid Parameters\",\n  \"moreInfo\":{\n    \"fieldLevelErrors\":[\n      {\n        \"fieldName\":\"/*/prospect/identificationDocumentDetails[idType!=\\\"\\\"]/idNumber\",\n        \"reasonCode\":\"Required/Invalid Format\",\n        \"errorMessage\":\"Value\"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}"``` 
and honestly I have no idea how to get the "errorMessage"

Answer (score 0):

You can apply:

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '{\n \"type\":\"invalid\",\n \"code\":\"invalidRequest\",\n \"details\":\"Missing or invalid Parameters\",\n \"moreInfo\":{\n \"fieldLevelErrors\":[\n {\n \"fieldName\":\"/*/prospect/identificationDocumentDetails[idType!=\\\"\\\"]/idNumber\",\n \"reasonCode\":\"Required/Invalid Format\",\n \"errorMessage\":\"Value\"\n }\n ]\n }\n}' response
)
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(response,'$.details') as details, JSON_EXTRACT(response,'$.moreInfo.fieldLevelErrors[0].errorMessage') as error
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

It returns the following result:

```
Row details                           error 
1   "Missing or invalid Parameters" "Value"
```